# More than one method annotated with @Before

Tags: java, junit

Can there be more than one method in a unit test annotated with `@Before` in junit? If so, which one would be executed first?

Comment: What happens if you test it before posting a question here?

Comment: But who guarantees the execution order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can have multiple `@Before` methods.
2. [Execution order](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-execution-order) in general is not guaranteed in JUnit, since it depends upon what order your JVM returns the methods in when JUnit reflectively gathers information about your test class. Keeping this in mind, there's no guarantees as to which method runs first, and order should not be relied upon.

Comment: they should add this info to the javadoc btw http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html